# SELECT-запрос в java

Tags: база-данных, jdbc, java, select, mysql

Использую PrepareStatement для выбора информации. Таблица имеет 3 поля: дата, время и сообщение. Метод deleteInformationFromDataBase удаляет конкретное сообщение (1 строку из таблицы). Теперь надо отправить запрос, который будет удалять все записи, в которых встречается конкретная дата. Не хочу создавать другой метод. Как, используя этот метод, передать СУБД нужный запрос?

типу: where date='2014-10-07' and time= * and message= *

Или просто в методе смотреть, какие параметры передаются. 
И если два последних = *, то формировать String SQL только с `prepareStatementObject.setString(1, date);`

```
public void deleteInformationFromDataBase(String date, String time,
    String message) {
String SQL = "DELETE FROM todolist WHERE date = ? and time = ? and message = ?";
try {
    prepareStatementObject = connectionObject.prepareStatement(SQL);
    prepareStatementObject.setString(1, date);
    prepareStatementObject.setString(2, time);
    prepareStatementObject.setString(3, message);
    prepareStatementObject.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте динамическое построение запроса:

1. В методе проверяйте на пустоту входные аргументы;
2. Если аргумент не пустой - добавлять его в условие "WHERE";
3. Если пустой - не учитывать его в условии.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте перед удалением проверку с селектом, если стрОки с такой датой, временем и сообщением нет, тогда удаляете все строки с нужной датой.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя использовать тот же SimpleDateFormat? В итоге можно будет передавать одно лишь значение даты класса Date.

И описать методы:

```
//передаем дату и сообщение
deleteInformationFromDataBase(Date date, String message);

//передаем дату
deleteInformationFromDataBase(Date date);

//передаем сообщение
deleteInformationFromDataBase(String message);
```

Два последних метода вызывают первый метод с параметрами, один из которых будет равен null в зависимости от вызывающего метода, соответственно.

Например:

```
//передаем сообщение
void deleteInformationFromDataBase(String message){
    deleteInformationFromDataBase(null, message);
}
```

В методе deleteInformationFromDataBase(Date,String) уже можно сделать проверку на передаваемые параметры, либо каждый метод реализовывать отдельно.